# How to Fetch Multiple Values in Textbox separated by comma

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have one drop-down box and one textbox. based on my drop-down selection textbox retrieve along with DB value. actually, its working fine without any issues. But my problem was database has two or more textbox values in particular drop-down selection. so I want to if multiple textbox values come to the same drop-down selection then it will display all values in textbox separated by the comma (,). Any help greatly appreciated.

**Here is my used code for your reference:-**

```
<select name="cat" id="cat">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value="1">Stencil Team</option>
        <option value="2">Tooling Team</option>
        <option value="3">IT</option>
        <option value="4">Manager</option>
        </select>

        <input name="phoneNumber" id="pnum"  type="text">
```

**Jquery:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cat").change(function(){
                    var deptid = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajaxdropdown.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {depart:deptid},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success:function(response){
                           var len = response.length;                       
                            $("#pnum").empty();
                            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                                var id1234 = response[i]['id123'];
                                var name1234 = response[i]['name123'];

                              $("#pnum").val(name1234);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
```

**Ajax Page:-**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
// Check connection
if (!$db) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$departid = $_POST['depart']; 

$sql = "SELECT Emp_Id,Mobile_Number FROM admin_panel WHERE Category=".$departid;

$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

$users_arr = array();

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
    $userid = $row['Emp_Id'];
    $name = $row['Mobile_Number'];
    $users_arr[] = array("id123" => $userid, "name123" => $name);
}

echo json_encode($users_arr);
?>
```

My Sample Data:-

```
Category Mobile_Number
  IT      9629292929
  IT      8888888888
  IT      5623566666
```

If I select the drop-down category "IT" then I want my textbox Mobile_Number output looks like this:-

```
9629292929,8888888888,5623566666
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: $name[] = $row['Mobile_Number']; and outside the while do implode(',',$name);

Comment: @Dananjaya Ariyasena pls see now i provided sample data :)

Comment: @Tom thanks ur suggestion if you don't mind can you please explain briefly how can i do it :)

Comment: if you are getting the mobile numbers in an `array` then you can make it into a comma separated string by just calling `$mobileNumberObj.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop over `json_encode()` d array.

And the join/implode the array values in a string combined by comma using PHP's in built function [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$arr = json_decode($yourArray);
$mobiles = array();
if (! empty($arr)) {
 foreach ($arr as $elem) {
  $mobiles[] = $elem['Mobile_Number'];
 }
}
$mobileStr = ! empty($mobiles) ? implode(',', $mobiles) : '';
```

Now, use this `$mobileStr` as `value="$mobileStr"` in your text box.

Answer (score 0):

You may use join function of javascript. Please refer following post.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_join